# How to correctly exit a while loop when the user inputs a specific integer

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I've written a program that will continue to print the line `printf("1 for Sum, 2 for Multiple, 3 for Newline Print");` until the user inputs a 0 to exit the loop and finish the program successfully. However, when I try inputting a 0 my program just continues to repeat the while loop, and I'm not quite sure as to why. What exactly am I doing wrong?

**MAIN**

```
int main(void){

    int integerArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int size = sizeof(integerArray) / sizeof(integerArray[0]);
    int choice;

    void(*funcPtr[3])(int, int[]) = {addMe, multiplyMe, myPrinter};

    while(1){
        printf("1 for Sum, 2 for Multiple, 3 for Newline Print");
        printf("\nEnter your Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if(choice == '0'){
            exit(0);
        }
        choice = choice - 1;
        (*funcPtr[choice])(size, integerArray);  
    }


}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 for Sum, 2 for Multiple, 3 for Newline Print
Enter your Choice: 0
1 for Sum, 2 for Multiple, 3 for Newline Print
Enter your Choice: 0
1 for Sum, 2 for Multiple, 3 for Newline Print
Enter your Choice:
```

Comment: try `break;` instead

Comment: @depperm that was the first thing I tried, the program still just continues to loop like above

Comment: Your debugger would have shown you that the statement was never reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(choice == '0')` should be `if(choice == 0)`. The `scanf` already translate the character `'0'` to the integer `0`, because of the `"%d"`.

As a side note: You should also check if the user enters a value `> 3`. Your program would do some odd things if you enter something invalid.